# i want to plot a 3D surface from {x,y,z}-measured data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation, matplotlib-3d

I have a measured data set, where I measured z by varying x and y. It turns out, that z is a complicated function of x and y. I wanted to illustrate this correlation by plotting a surface in the same 3D scattered plot.

[image: 3D plot of the measured data set]

For the surface plot I tried to interpolate the data with `scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator`, but I always get the error `"ValueError: different number of values and points"`.
With the interpolated dataset, I hope I could plot a surface.
Can someone help me fix this problem or has a better idea how to make a surface plot without interpolation?

Here is my (non-working) code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
    
path = '...'
csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt") 

for file in csv_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1, sep=" ", index_col = False,  names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    X = df['x'].tolist()
    Y = df['y'].tolist()
    Z = df['z'].tolist()

data = np.array([X, Y, Z]) 
x_range = np.linspace(0, 250, 100)
y_range = np.linspace(0, 25, 100)
z_range = np.linspace(0.6, 1.3, 100)
X_range, Y_range, Z_range = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range, z_range)

interpol =  scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator((X_range, Y_range, Z_range), data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(X, Y, Z)
ax.plot_surface(interpol, color='red', alpha=0.5)
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_xticks((np.arange(0, 250, 50)))
ax.set_yticks((np.arange(0, 22.5, 5)))
ax.set_zticks((np.arange(0.6, 1.3, 0.2)))
plt.show()
```

I don't know how to upload my data txt-file, so here is my data:

```
x   y    z
0.37393 15.98951 1.11199
0.26065 16.62144 1.13697
0.15455 16.83967 1.1116
0.08807999999999999 18.26241 1.1059700000000001
0.04881 19.29715 1.04775
0.02442 19.75512 0.97696
0.90218 4.36669 0.693865
0.9276333333333333 4.928543333333334 0.7059633333333334
0.753 5.31827 0.705565
0.6702950000000001 5.569685 0.708385
0.60643 5.88769 0.708175
0.56761 6.20349 0.71373
0.54791 6.43602 0.72013
0.52895 6.67366 0.72203
0.51629 6.97619 0.73246
0.50601 7.36988 0.72826
0.50362 7.8074 0.74285
0.50803 8.42439 0.75707
0.6249 9.16996 0.7708579999999999
0.5892525 10.30973 0.815395
0.6302075 10.738597500000001 0.8327375
0.67013 11.21011 0.85277
0.73736 11.68319 0.88171
0.7835766666666667 11.876596666666666 0.9103033333333334
0.8719049999999999 12.454065 0.91974
0.92747 12.86237 0.97445
0.94691 13.15212 1.00631
0.94647 13.41636 1.02952
0.91507 13.73602 1.04807
0.84798 13.93873 1.06563
0.74669 14.54955 1.07413
0.6323733333333333 14.94551 1.1022083333333332
0.50563 15.40169 1.09873
1.35108 4.47333 0.7049
1.11833 4.66972 0.70097
1.09603 14.94551 1.0897
1.67474 9.16996 0.76182
1.99625 14.94551 1.08341
3.15564 9.16996 0.7682249999999999
3.84951 14.94551 1.087
3.82158 19.75512 0.98298
6.15946 9.16996 0.78639
7.61186 19.29715 1.08292
12.41109 9.16996 0.78873
13.76003 18.26241 1.05921
14.85856 14.94551 1.09684
24.12246 16.83967 1.06913
31.23807 14.94551 1.08555
40.70883 16.62144 1.05756
53.85186 9.16996 0.80394
58.47276 15.98951 1.03439
79.05656 7.36988 0.82303
79.11868 15.40169 1.03178
79.61848 8.42439 0.83851
80.11088 9.16996 0.80823
80.58521 6.97619 0.82595
82.34242 9.16996 0.8240149999999999
82.53909 6.67366 0.83048
85.25811 6.43602 0.81826
88.68029 6.20349 0.81364
90.60147 10.23518 0.87314
92.18659 10.35662 0.86784
92.52619 5.98135 0.82314
93.53199 10.41194 0.86381
95.56544 10.66566 0.87352
96.40025 14.94551 1.02913
96.52367 5.79403 0.83129
97.32582 10.74821 0.87792
99.10386 14.94551 1.018805
99.77603 10.77026 0.88455
102.45517 9.16996 0.79895
102.80512 11.12437 0.88758
105.97367 11.29585 0.89341
106.5373 5.49968 0.83492
109.38083 11.32421 0.89735
115.02618 11.68319 0.90752
115.74819 9.16996 0.79136
116.12033 14.54955 1.00781
117.65438 9.16996 0.78569
120.40083 11.84231 0.92171
120.57418 9.16996 0.80856
123.13233 14.94551 1.01836
125.83722 11.94517 0.92766
132.32767 13.93873 0.99304
132.57461 12.33382 0.92959
134.32769 5.00722 0.84645
138.90469 12.57431 0.9436
139.00953 14.94551 0.96929
141.92936 14.94551 0.97257
142.6263 4.93312 0.84379
142.52708 13.73602 0.98265
144.67857 12.86237 0.95324
147.48769 13.15212 0.96137
147.14701 13.41636 0.97025
151.98434 4.84529 0.84247
235.5091 4.33268 0.85618
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  How would you plot a surface from that set of points?  What would it look like?

Comment: You may use `.plot_trisurf`

Comment: I'm not sure, something like a fluttering towel. I can't fit this data so my only idea was to interpolate and then plot the interpolated data points and try to connect them to a kind of a grid surface

Comment: As per the duplicate(s), with `.plot_trisurf`: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XtVR.png) and [code and plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdoIo.png)